# Audio or video lectures of Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan zt"l

Tags: rabbis, recording, rabbi-aryeh-kaplan

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan zt"l, wrote many interesting [*articles*](http://www.aish.com/authors/48865952.html) and [*books*](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=aryeh%20kaplan) in his life. However, does anyone know if there are an *audio* of *video* lectures of him?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the original recording of the famed Age of The Universe speech which was given at the Midwinter Conference of the Association of Orthodox Jewish Scientists on February 18, 1979 (later published in book form; [see here](https://www.simpletoremember.com/faqs/Kaplan-SimpleToRemember.com.pdf)), visit [bitly.com/aryehkaplan.](https://bitly.com/aryehkaplan)

[Here is a radio interview](https://www.mixcloud.com/max-smile/interview-with-rabbi-aryeh-kaplan/) with Rabbi Kaplan (54 min.) mainly concerning kabbalah and meditation.

Recorded on June 6, 1980 - it is transcribed [here.](http://www.nyspirit.com/in-the-spirit/conversations-spirit-part-8-rabbi-aryeh-kaplan/)

The image presented on the website is not Rabbi Kaplan, rather his [colleague](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqCr93tQT8w).

See [this other answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57464/16706) for a [**video**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NRiJrEdelAU&t=210s) of the Rabbi.

It is to be noted, that in one of the (posthumous) books, in the preface, there is mention of an extant tape collection of certain lectures. As well, during his life he did quite a number of radio and television interviews in the New York area (significantly more radio, though). Where there are archives and records of radio etc. and of New York etc. there surely exists more content of him. But until then, see above. It seems, about 10 years ago, an effort was made to gather some of his lectures on [a dedicated website](https://web.archive.org/web/20110624101047/http://aryehkaplan.org/), but it does not appear to have taken off the ground.

See further [here](https://kavvanah.blog/2018/10/23/rabbi-aryeh-kaplan-on-experience-consciousness-and-method/):

> Finally, Perle Besserman, one of his long time students, and the one who promoted him for his radio and TV interviews, asked him about the role of gender in these experiences in that it always was a male mystic who identified with the male zeir anpin making love to female shekinah.

And [here](https://kavvanah.blog/2018/10/15/rabbi-aryeh-kaplans-god/):

> I listened to the audio of the classes on which the book Sefer Yetzirah was based. In the discussion, he defined meditation as an expansion of consciousness, alternately he said “I believe that meditation is the channeling of the spiritual energy.”

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://youtu.be/NRiJrEdelAU) is the only video I've found of him.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a recording.

http://torahdownloads.com/shiur-18963.html

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Could you [edit] this to add a little bit about what the video is?  A lecture title, for example?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be the interview with Dr. Russel Barber. Same as video links above.