# Audio or video of Rabbi Michel Ber Weismandl zt”l

Tags: rabbis, recording

<sub>[(related)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57463/16706)</sub>

[Rabbi Michel Ber Weismandl zt"l](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Michael_Dov_Weissmandl), saved many people during the holocaust, but also was a noted Torah scholar genius. They published [some](http://hebrewbooks.org/42028) of his work after his death. However, does anyone know if there is audio or video [lectures] (content) of him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new documentary “The Giant” by Project Witness, at around 45 minutes, there are three clips of footage totaling about 30 seconds in total.

https://projectwitness.org/in-the-footsteps-of-the-giant-temp/  (Usually $15 - Free now)

Comment: Care to add a link?

Comment: @Oliver it’s on their website behind a paywall.

Comment: Seems to be free now!  https://projectwitness.org/in-the-footsteps-of-the-giant-temp/  - Maybe because of Coronavirus? https://projectwitness.org/view-on-demand/